# Is the Google Drive API the same as the Google Drive Android API?

Tags: google-drive-api

We recently received an email notifying us of the Google Drive Android API deprecation in February, referencing that one of our applications uses this.

After looking further, our app uses the "Google Drive API," but we're wanting to know if that's the exact same thing as the "Google Drive Android API" that the email/deprecation references.

Thanks